# Can't use $1 in basename wordpress filter

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok this is hard to explain in the heading. But I've made this function in my functions.php

Where i add a title tag to all image links with the image caption. By finding the filename and look it up in the DB, finding the ID and by that getting the correct caption.

Here is the function

```
add_filter('the_content', 'addshadowboxrel', 12);
add_filter('get_comment_text', 'addshadowboxrel');
function addshadowboxrel ($content) {
  global $wpdb;

    $pattern = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([^>]*).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i";
    $path = '$3.$4';
    $attachment_url = basename($path);  

    $attachment_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT wposts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '%s' AND wposts.post_type = 'attachment'", $attachment_url ) );
    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
    $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 title="'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'" rel="lightbox"$6>$7</a>';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Everything works: If I replace the $path with the actual path insted of '$3.$4'.

But the basename function dont work as it is here?

Comment: Whats the actual `$path` value looks like?

Comment: If i place it in the output string inside title '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 title="$3.$4$" rel="lightbox"$6>$7</a>'; it shows the image path... $3 is the path and file name and $4 is the extension.

Comment: It showed because `$3.$4` being used in `preg_replace` function where it can be recognize as capturing groups. Where `basename` isn't know about the regex captured groups.

Comment: Aha... So it's only recognized by the preg_replace. That make sens! :)

Comment: Damn then the function will never work. Because all the magic happens inside the preg_replace, and I cant change anyting on the way.. back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

Where have you declared `$3` and `$4`? Variable names cannot start with a number. So:

```
$3
$4
```

Cannot be valid variables. Can you change them to:

```
$n3
$n4
```

Instead? And try! This could be basic but this WOULD be the reason! :)

Also consider using the function `preg_match_all`. Check out [Pattern Syntax](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) for more details.

Comment: this line works fine: $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 title="'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'" rel="lightbox"$6>$7</a>'; So think that it's a wordpress thing...

Comment: With a "$n3.$n4" the $attachment->post_excerpt shows full post excerpt.. So that didn't solve it...

Comment: @MartinLyder Did you try `preg_replace`?

Comment: I didn't now that it had to do with the preg_replace as olso Rahil Wazir mentioned in the comments above :) I'll try to filter the path with preg_replace...